# Как убрать сдвиг сайта при появлении полосы прокрутки?

Tags: html, css

сабж. При появлении полосы сайт сдвигается влево на несколько пикселей. как убрать этот эффект? чтобы внезависимости от наличия/отсутствия полосы сайт был всегда на 1 месте.

Comment: я бы не запаривался по этой "проблеме"... :) Наполните сайт контентом и проблема уйдет ;)

Comment: Повтор вопроса [79543](http://hashcode.ru/questions/79543)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

сделай полосу прокрутки видимой всегда, подругому никак. либо наоборот ее убрать визуально.

читай про [overflow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

Comment: тогда как это сделал контакт?

Comment: А контакт все javascript'ом вычисляет и фиксирует.

Comment: да, тож мельком глянул -- там все на css и javascript управление отображением именно для сколлбаров сделано. посмотрите firebug'ом

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы ширина страницы не изменялась при появлении скролла можно воспользоваться динамическим паддингом:

```css
body { padding: 0 calc(20px - (100vw - 100%)) 0 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html {margin-right: calc(-1 * (100vw - 100%));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Александр Глазунов дал хороший вариант но забыл добавить overflow-x hidden без этого появляется горизонтальная прокрутка.

```
html {
   margin-right: calc(-1 * (100vw - 100%));
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

или

```
html {
    width:100vw;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: А с `overflow-x: hidden;` скрывается часть контента рядом со скроллом.

Answer (score -1):

Только-что столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Контент после загрузки дергается влево из-за исчезновения справа полосы прокрутки. Решается проблема установкой свойства overfow-y: hidden для проблемного контейнера, что изначально не дает появляться этой полосе.

Answer (score -2):

Может так?

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Интересно)) а как прокручивать контент?

Comment: колесиком ;) оно будет работать.

Comment: @thunder не будет